# Dual boot windows 10/ubuntu not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, grub2

Yesterday i installed ubuntu on my secondary ssd and it has been working just fine, but when i try to boot "windows boot manager" it opens windows in repair mode and says it cant be fixed, but if i use BIOS boot "windows boot manager" it works fine.

I tried doing this, https://wiki.debian.org/DualBoot/Windows10 but it just says it cant find ntldr when i boot that option.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is install UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI can you directly boot Windows from UEFI one time boot menu, same key you used to select flash drive installer. Grub only boots working Windows. And that also means Windows cannot be hibernated or need chkdsk. Windows with updates turns fast start up/hibernation back on. So your regularly have to fix. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: As far as i can tell both windows and ubuntu installations are UEFI and i can boot windows from UEFI Bios.